# Переформировать строку

Tags: php

Есть строка `$str = 25-12-2017 15:55`

Из этой строки нужно сделать такую: `2017-12-25 15:55`

Вариант ли использовать *explode* или есть наиболее лучшее решение?
Предпочтительно решение с минимумом кода.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php для того чтобы вернуть дату, отформатированную согласно переданному формату. А потом выводить в нужном формате

```
$input_date = '25-12-2017 15:55';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $input_date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: то что нужно! спасибо!